# Program for finding duplicate photos?

Tags: macos, photos

I used to use [Visipics](http://www.visipics.info/index.php?title=Main_Page) and completely loved it, it's simple yet powerful. However it's only for Windows which I have abandoned. Are there any OS X (Lion) programs that do the same? I'm sure there are, am just wondering if there are any that stand out. After taking all the files from multiple computers and putting them on one hard drive to be organized and regrouped I'm sure there are a lot I will find of varying quality. I would prefer free software, since Visipics is free and worked fine, however if there's something outstanding that costs money I'll consider it.

Comment: If you can't find a native OS X App you can always run VisPics under OS X using Wine and XQuartz.  I download it and tested it under OS X 10.8.5 and found duplicates I didn't even know I had.  Have a look at: [Photos Duplicate Cleaner](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photos-duplicate-cleaner/id592704001?mt=12)

Answer (score -2):

I use photo fixer pro and works well too bad in the past with iphoto there was an auto select photo app now you have to select each one and for me its a pain why well because i have 80,570 photos mixed with videos